# How to Resolve search with Stop words

Tags: elasticsearch

I am implementing an application using elastic search.

Here is the sample of the search query

```
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.fuzzyLikeThisFieldQuery("_all").likeText("to"));
```

When I am trying to search with *"stop words"* It returns 0 documents.
How to overcome this?

Comment: Have you specified an analyzer for the _all field?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of a document that's in your index that you expect to match? That'll help us figure out what's going on :)

Comment: i did not specified any analyzer for _all fields

Comment: [Read the docs on `match` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/), it has a parameter `zero_terms_query` which should do what you are asking.